# What is this game with a red cricket pushing a ball?

Tags: game-identification

[image: mystery game]

It looks like a 2d platformer with a red cricket as a protagonist. Either Grapefruit or oranges or in the game as a collectable. I saw this in a video and I'm interested in playing it.

Comment: This game is wonderful!  Pinball Metroidvania.  See answers for the name.

Comment: Did you see this is the video about that guys wife and "What's it like to not be a gamer?"
Good video :)

Answer (score 31):

[*Yoku’s Island Express*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoku's_Island_Express). Searching by image on Google led me to [this page](https://www.portallos.com.br/2018/09/03/yokus-island-express-pinballvania-impressoes/) with the name.

See the fruit counter matching your screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13):

The game is Yoku's Island Express, released in May 2018 for PS4, Xbox One, Nintendo Switch, and PC. Here's a screenshot from the [Steam page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/334940/Yokus_Island_Express/) for comparison:

[image: Screenshot of the game]